# String Date Handling with OffSet

Tags: java, timezone, offset, timezone-offset, datetimeoffset

I have date-time in persistent storage received from an external system. I need to use this and set as a Date type for a java library routine. This messes up the same to be set under the current jvm timezone. I understand that an offset may not necessarily corresponding timezone, but, this is messing up a lot of things.

eg:

```
2020-08-14T08:59:34.961+05:30
```

Sample code:

```
String dateFromDatabase = "2020-08-14T08:59:34.961+05:30";
SimpleDateFormat outputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
Date tempDate=outputDateFormat.parse(dateFromDatabase);
System.out.println( tempDate );
```

Sample output:

```
Thu Aug 13 23:29:34 EDT 2020
```

Expected output:

```
it should not return the EDT based datetime
```

How can I keep my date with the correct offset?

Any suggestions/ recommendations on how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: use the not-so-new `java.time` [package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html): `ZonedDateTime.parse(dateFromDatabase)`

Comment: @user15244370 Yes, i tried that, but, it does not give me the Date type which is what I need to pass it to the library routine... Any step to convert to Date type is a problem.

Comment: `Date` is just an instant in time - if you print it (`toString`) you will get its representation using the actual default `TimeZone` - so the *library* is probably also using it (try, for testing, changing the `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone(zonedDate.getZone())` (which probably may mess up somewhere else in code)

Comment: As i understood you want to parse `2020-08-14T08:59:34.961+05:30 ` and keep the time as is like `08:59:34.961`, does that right?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead just use `OffsetDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1):

The `java.util.Date` object is not a real date-time object like the [modern date-time types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html); rather, it represents the number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT` (or UTC). It means that irrespective of the location in the world, a `Date` object represents the same number (milliseconds from the epoch). When you print an object of `java.util.Date`, its `toString` method returns the date-time in the JVM's timezone, calculated from this milliseconds value. In order to print the date-time in a different timezone, we set the timezone to `SimpleDateFormat` and obtain the formatted string from it.

If you do not like the output like `Thu Aug 13 23:29:34 EDT 2020`, which is the string returned by `Date#toString` in your timezone (and will be different in different timezones), there are two options:

1. Represent the `Date` in milliseconds (as described above, it will be the same at any location in the world) obtained using [`Date#getTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime--).
2. Keep the original string, `2020-08-14T08:59:34.961+05:30` as it is because it already represents the date-time in the [ISO8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Dates).

Note that the `java.util` date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**A demo of the modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String dateFromDatabase = "2020-08-14T08:59:34.961+05:30";
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateFromDatabase);
        System.out.println(zdt);

        // If at all you need java.util.Date, you can get it from Instant
        Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
        Date date = Date.from(instant);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-08-14T08:59:34.961+05:30
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>